# How to read yaml file and create stages dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For our backend testing application, we have a use-case where we want to generate all stages dynamically. Right now, we are doing this by defining one object type parameter stages and then looping over those stages parameter to create all stages. And the value that we are passing for the object type parameter is yaml array. This approach is working fine and is mentioned on this blob - https://codingwithtaz.blog/2022/04/10/dynamic-multistage-azure-pipelines-part-1/

Object type parameter is mentioned here in the azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/parameters-parameter?view=azure-pipelines

The problem with this approach is that we are hitting the size limit on this parameter. Since we have lots of stages, the size of yaml array is huge and so when we are trying to run it with that yaml, we are getting the error that size limit exceeded.

So, as a solution we want to store the yaml array in the file and we want the azure pipeline to read that file and create these stages dynamically. But I could not find a way to implement this, can someone please help with the implementation part of this solution.

**Error screenshot :-**

[image]

Comment: Viewing the blog mentioned by you, you are using "stepList" parameters. We can't store the yaml array in the file and let the azure pipeline to read that file because parameter doesn't support template. Besides, even if steps are not defined in parameters but stored in template, the final expanded yaml file may still exceed the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over object parameters is performed at compile time. But at compile time, we cannot read the array value in the file.

Therefore, we cannot first read the array value in the file and then set the parameters to create stages in one Pipeline.

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can use two pipelines to achieve this. One pipeline is used to read array in the file and pass the array value to another pipeline via Rest API: [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) , the other pipeline uses object type parameters to loop all instances and set the stages numbers.

Refer to the following steps:

Array file example:

[image]

For the pipeline read array in the file and pass the array value to another pipeline:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $test = Get-Content -Path "test.txt"
   
   echo $test
   
   $token = "PAT"
   
   $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
   
   $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
   
   $JSON = "
   {
   
     `"resources`": {
       `"repositories`": {
        `"self`": {
           `"refName`": `"refs/heads/main`"
         }
       }
     },
     `"templateParameters`": {
       `"instances`":`"$test`"
      },
   
   
   
   }"
   
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

For the pipeline to set the stages, you can define the object parameters and loop all values.

```
parameters:
  - name: instances
    type: object
    default: []

stages:
- ${{ each instance in parameters.instances }}: 
  - stage: test${{instance}}
    jobs:
    - job:
      steps: 
      - script: echo ${{ instance }}
```

Result:

[image]